# How to check array equality with reduce, using destructuring and recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, reduce, destructuring

How would you check two arrays for equality using the reduce helper, destructuring and recursion?

```
const isEqual = (arr1, arr2) => {
  // use reduce helper to check arrays for equality, use destructuring and recursion
}
```

So obviously `isEqual([1,2,3], [1,2,3])` should return `true` for example and something like `isEqual(["hello", "there"], ["good", "morning"])` should return `false`.

Comment: please add an example of the wanted methods. what would you like to do with `reduce`, for example?

Answer (score 4):

You can stringify the arrays by using `JSON.stringify()` before the comparison:

```js
const isEqual = (arr1, arr2) => {
  var flag = JSON.stringify(arr1)==JSON.stringify(arr2)? true : false;
  return flag;
}
console.log(isEqual([1,2,3], [1,2,3])); //true
console.log(isEqual(["hello", "there"], ["good", "morning"])); //false
console.log(isEqual([1, '2', 3], [1,2,3])); //false
```

Comment: @I_ATE_YOUR_WORK_FILES, do you think the numbers and string representation of the numbers are equal?

Comment: @I_ATE_YOUR_WORK_FILES, please see the updated answer to check how the function return `false` for the input you have provided......thanks..

Comment: Wow that is quite awesome! Looks like I learned something cool... thanks a lot really!

Removed my misleading comment

Comment: That's a smart and great idea, easy to implement, easy to understand, I was about to think about some recursive algorithms. However, I suggest you to `.toLowerCase()` both json to make sure the comparison is case insensitive (if needed)

Comment: @Cid if you really do want case insensitive, then use `.toLocaleLowerCase` otherwise you'd have problems in Turkey where `i` and `I` are NOT different cases of the same letter but with a locale-insensitive case conversion, they suddenly are.

Comment: @vlaz They are 2 differents letters ?

Comment: @Cid yes, [in Turkish language, they are](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursive approach with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and a check for the elements and by checking the length'.

```js
const isEqual = ([v, ...a], [w, ...b]) => {
    return v === w && a.length === b.length && (a.length === 0 || isEqual(a, b));
}

console.log(isEqual([1, 2], [1, 2, 3]));
console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]));
console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]));
console.log(isEqual(["hello", "there"], ["good", "morning"]));
```